# Android: How to go back using searchview' back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, searchview

I put into menu the searchview.

[image]

Im my main activity I did this:

```
public class FirstActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
           ..................
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
```

> When I click the search icon I replace the current fragment with the search fragment.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction() .replace(R.id.container,SearchActivity.newInstance(...)).commit();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I would like to intercept the back (see image) to back in the previous fragment